# TyperError: 'function' object has no attribute '_getitem_'

Tags: python, scipy, constraints, typeerror

Currently, I am working on my graduation project, but I have some troubles with my code. Is there maybe anybody that could help to solve my error. I am trying to optimize the profit generated out of water.

The error I get is the following one (appears in the if line of the constraint):

```
TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

My code:

```
#constants
Ymax=8              #tonne/ha
ky=1.25
Numbas=3            #3 subbasins
Nummon=12           #12 months is a year. 
c_hydro=0.9         #Conversion rate m3 to kWh
LBPmaize=316413     #LBP/tonne
LBPhydro=55         #LBP/kWh
alpha=0.7
p1=0.35              #soil moisture depletion factor for no stress

#parameters 
S0=[207.112, 150, 161.398]
A=[74571.9, 1537.8, 6645.7]         #total area per subbasin
a=[0.423, 0.959, 0.473]             #part of area used for irrigation
R=[0.2, 0.3, 0.5]

Qhydromatrix=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]

#Definitions
def profit(x,sign=-1):
    x=[]*(Numbas*Nummon)
    return sign * (alpha*Yasum*LBPmaize)   

def ETa(x):
   for i in range(0,(Nummon*Numbas)):
       ETa=[]*(Numbas*Nummon)
       if np.multiply(x,p1)>ETmax_maize:
          ETa[i]=ETmax_maize[i]
      else:
          ETa[i]=np.multiply(x[i],p1)
    return ETa

def Yasum(ETa):
    Yasum=0
    for j in range(0,Numbas):
        for i in range(0,Nummon):
            ETasum=sum(ETa[j*Nummon:(j+1)*Nummon])
            ETmaxsum=sum(ETmax_maize[j*Nummon:(j+1)*Nummon])
            Ya=((-1*Ymax*ky)*(1-(ETasum/ETmaxsum))+Ymax)*A[j]*a[j]
        Yasum=Yasum+Ya
    return Yasum

def constraint(x):
    for j in range(0,Numbas):
        for i in range(0,Nummon):
            if (i-(j*Nummon))==0:
                x[i+(j*Nummon)]-((1-R[j])*S0[j])+ETa[i+(j*Nummon)+11]-P[i+(j*Nummon)+11]-Rdown[i+(j*Nummon)]
            else: 
               ETa[i+(j*Nummon)-1]-((1-R[j])*x[i+(j*Nummon)-1])+x[i+(j*Nummon)]-P[i+(j*Nummon)-1]-Rdown[i+(j*Nummon)]
    return x
con2=({'type':'ineq','fun':constraint})  

x0=[100]*(Nummon*Numbas)

sol=minimize(profit, x0,method='SLSQP', constraints=con2)
```

Comment: Note that `[] * n == []`.

Comment: `__getitem__` is produced by a `[...]`, as done when indexing a list, dictionary or array.  The error means that a function is being called with `fn[...]` rather than `fn(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this error means you have an expression `f[x]` where `f` is a function.

You have several problems in your code, but the error comes from this line:

```
   ETa[i+(j*Nummon)-1]-((1-R[j])*x[i+(j*Nummon)-1])+x[i+(j*Nummon)]-P[i+(j*Nummon)-1]-Rdown[i+(j*Nummon)]
   # ^ this is a function
```

You defined a function called `ETa`. You also use local variables named `ETa`. This is not a good idea in general. In the last function, you don't have a local variable in this name, so the name is looked up at the global scope - and that's a function; functions cannot be accessed this way.

Other issues with your code:

- In the function profit you are assigning the parameter, and not using it: `x=[]*(Numbas*Nummon)`. This change is local, and has no effect on the argument passed to the function.
- You are using expressions of the form `[] * some_number` in two places. This is meaningless - repeating the empty list returns the empty list.
- In the function `constraint` you are returning `x`, but not changing it in any way. Did you intend to change it from within `profit`? Because you can't.
- In the same function, both `if` and `else` branch goes on to evaluate expression, without any effect.

Note that those problems are unrelated to the logic of your code.

Important style issues:

- Please use `snake_case` variable names. This does not affect the behavior of the code, but helps other people read it, so it will help you in getting feedback. Similarly, put spaces around operators such as `=`, `+`, etc.
- If expressions get too long, break it into several statement using local variable.
- If an expression repeats itself (such as `j * Nummon` above), put its value in a variable.